# rewrite query replacing not in

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

I want to re-write the below query in a way to remove `NOT IN` is that possible ?

```
select * from TRX_T TT, TRX_SUB TS
where TT.CODE=TS.CODE
and TT.SUBID= TS.ID
and TS.VALUE=1
and TS.CODE=1
AND TS.ID=17
AND TT.STATUS NOT IN('T','R','C')
```

If the status was `IN` I would then use `union all`

The reason I want to re-write because the below oracle recommendation.

> The predicate "TT"."STATUS"<>'C' used at line ID 5 of the execution
>   plan   contains an expression on indexed column "STATUS". This 
>   expression prevents   the optimizer from efficiently using indices on
>   table TT.

Number of Distinct values

```
    T       264
    C   5489709
    D      2987
    J       924
    L    529430
    R     39382
    S      5449
```

The index on `TRX_T` is like this: `(CODE,SUBID,TYPE,STATUS,NO_SL)`

Comment: Do you have an identified performance problem with the query ... a reason to believe that it ought to be able to run faster other than this Oracle recommendation? The recommendation is only relevant if the alternative that it offers (indexed access on the TRX_T table) would improve performance – it's quite possible that it won't.

Comment: What does the explain plan say? Does it use the index? The query is very simple after all. You are selecting one or zero `trx_sub` rows, because of `TS.ID = 17`. This gets you the one row with ID 17, but if `code` or `value` doesn't equal 1, you dismiss it. For this one `trx_sub` record you get related `trx_t` rows and you have an index on the relevant columns `code` and `subid`. Looks fine. How many rows are in table `trx_t` and how many rows does your query typically retrieve?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner both of them around 6 million , the explain plan showing reading indexes on all columns

Comment: So there is six million rows in `trx_t`. And your query retrieves how many of these? You say the index is being used, so it's obviously a small percentage only. Then where is the problem? Oracle seems to think that `AND TT.STATUS IN('D','J','L','S')` and an index on `(CODE,SUBID,STATUS)` would be preferable, but how much faster would this get the query? I wouldn't expect much of a change in speed.

Comment: On a sidenote: Comma-separated joins were made redundant in the SQL standard of 1992. It took Oracle nine years to adopt it, but that is still seventeen years ago now. Please use proper joins (`from trx_t tt inner join trx_sub ts on ...`).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to tune a query you need to understand your data model and your data. The optimiser says it cannot efficiently use an index on `TRX_T`. Let's look at that compound index:

- `CODE` : used in join criteria
- `SUBID` : used in join criteria
- `TYPE` : not used
- `STATUS` : could be used as filter ?
- `NO_SL` : not used

Your query uses three of the five indexed columns. But because you have a NOT IN expression on `STATUS` the optimiser doesn't use the index to evaluate the filter. So it reads every record in `TRX_T` which matches a record in `TRX_SUB` and evaluates the filter on the table.

Perhaps if you expressed the condition positively as `TT.STATUS IN ('D','J','L', 'S')` then the optimizer might be able to use a SKIP SCAN to evaluate the filter on the index.

However, the index usage would be more efficient if the `TRX_T.TYPE` were used as filter ( or if the order of the index columns were re-arranged to have `STATUS` before `TYPE` but don't do this as it might destabilise other queries).

Another option would be to rewrite the expression as a NOT IN subquery (if you have **no** null values in  `(TRX_T.CODE, TRX_T.SUBID)` otherwise as a NOT EXISTS subquery):

```
select * from TRX_T TT, TRX_SUB TS
where TT.CODE=TS.CODE
and TT.SUBID= TS.ID
and TS.VALUE=1
and TS.CODE=1
AND TS.ID=17
AND (TT.CODE, TT.SUBID) NOT IN
     (select x.CODE, x.SUBID
      from trx_t x
      where x.status in ('T','R','C')
     )
```

However, the number of TRX_T records which have STATUS values in that list is very large - they are the majority of your table - so evaluating that subquery might well be more expensive than what you have at the moment.

Please note, the usual caveats apply. Tuning queries on StackOverflow is a mug's game. Too much information is missing (data volumes, skew, other indexes, explain plans, etc) for us to to do anything other than guess.

Comment: Yes I agree about tuning queries is a bit tricky on SO. That's why I was asking to re write the query, I can create a covering index that covers all the column it might help. as per `TT.STATUS IN ('D','J','L', 'S')`  sometime new status will be inserted so it wont be helpful.

Comment: Exactly why this is a mug's game. All we can do is suggest different ways for you to rewrite you query, most if which won't make any improvement or will even make things worse, or won't work for some other reason (such as a new status).

Answer (score 1):

use explicit join and not in could be replaced by below way

```
   select * from TRX_T TT
   join  TRX_SUB TS
    on  TT.CODE=TS.CODE and TT.SUBID= TS.ID
    where TS.VALUE=1
    and TS.CODE=1
    AND TS.ID=17 
    and not exists
    ( select 1 from TRX_T t1 where t1.CODE=TT.code
     and (t1.STATUS ='T' OR t1.STATUS='R' or t1.STATUS='C')
    )
```

Comment: This is not an equivalent query. You need to use Boolean AND rather than OR.

Comment: oracle actually reading it like this as you notice from its recommendation and its saying not helpful

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `left join` and filter out `TT2.status is null` so it will give you those records which are `not in ('T','R','C')`

```
select * from TRX_T TT
   join  TRX_SUB TS on  TT.CODE=TS.CODE and TT.SUBID= TS.ID
   left join (select * from TRX_T where STATUS in ('T','R','C')) TT2 on 
   TT.CODE=TT2.CODE and TT.SUBID= TT2.SUBID
where TS.VALUE=1 and TS.CODE=1 AND TS.ID=17 and TT2.status is null
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `minus` *set operator* as

```
select *
  from TRX_T TT
  join TRX_SUB TS
    on ( TT.CODE = TS.CODE
     and TT.SUBID = TS.ID )
 where TS.VALUE = 1
   and TS.CODE = 1
   and TS.ID = 17
minus
select *
  from TRX_T TT
  join TRX_SUB TS
    on ( TT.CODE = TS.CODE
     and TT.SUBID = TS.ID )
 where TS.VALUE = 1
   and TS.CODE = 1
   and TS.ID = 17
   and TT.STATUS in ('T', 'R', 'C');
```

P.S. Yes, `Not in` is mostly problematic from the performance view, and as a side not using `nvl` function shouldn't be forgotten when using `Not in`.

Comment: Whether this is more efficient rather depends on how expensive it is is to evaluate the join on TRXT_T and TRX_SUB.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below, you can use 'except':

```
SELECT * 
FROM   trx_t TT, 
       trx_sub TS 
WHERE  TT.code = TS.code 
       AND TT.subid = TS.id 
       AND TS.value = 1 
       AND TS.code = 1 
       AND TS.id = 17 
EXCEPT 
SELECT * 
FROM   trx_t TT, 
       trx_sub TS 
WHERE  TT.status = 'T' 
        OR TT.status = 'R' 
        OR TT.status = 'C'
```

Comment: Funny to see that somebody upvoted this. Obviously they also don't know that EXCEPT is not valid in Oracle. It should be MINUS.

Comment: Alas, there is no evidence that this will result in more efficient execution plan. The status values of ('T','R' and 'C') account for more than 90% of all the rows in TRX_T so assembling the result set of the lower subquery will be expensive. And that's before we consider the catastrophic effect of the Product we will get from the cross join of TRX_T and TRX_SUB.

Comment: Oh sorry ,I think its sql

Comment: As @APC has said, these are all just guesses. I would  suggest getting a SQL Monitor report and present facts.

Comment: you are Bill Gates